# Cannot read AsyncStorage value on React Native app startup

Tags: ios, react-native, react-redux

I am using React Native with Redux. The following code is used to create the Redux store, and uses AsyncStorage to check if the user is logged in by checking the presence of an authToken.

```
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import {persistStore} from 'redux-persist';

async function getAuthToken() {
  return await AsyncStorage.getItem('authToken');
}

export function createStore(onCompletion:() => void):any {
  ...

  const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    {
      auth: {
        authenticated: !!getAuthToken()
      }
    },
    enhancer);

  persistStore(store, {
    storage: AsyncStorage,
  },
  onCompletion);
}
```

The creation of the store:

```
export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      store: createStore(...),
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={this.state.store}>
        <AppNavigator />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

The `authToken` value get correctly set once the user logs in, and is removed once the user logs out. But the authToken does not get persisted after the app is relaunched. The first call to `getAuthToken` always returns this junk value from `AsyncStorage`:

> { _45: 0, _81: 0, _65: null, _54: null }

Why could this be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Now you're returning a promise from AsyncStorage, you need to return the token value. Try:

```
async function getAuthToken() {
  return await AsyncStorage.getItem('authToken').then((token) => token);
}
```

Comment: This is not working for me, and I still get the same result. My understanding was that "await" is synchronous already. I'm also using the same "await" pattern to synchronously fetch the authToken from AsyncStorage and send in the HTTP header, which is working.

Answer (score 0):

With hooks you useEffect

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export function App() {
  const [token, setToken] = useState<string>();
  useEffect(()=>{
    (async function() {
      setToken(await AsyncStorage.getItem());
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    })();
  },[]);
  if (token) {
    return (<View><Text>{token}</Text></View>);
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```